# Using JsTestDriver's basePath to specify where to load fixture data from

Tags: javascript, js-test-driver

I am trying to load HTML fixture data into a JsTestDriver test environment. I can get it to work when the `jsTestDriver.conf` file is at the top level of my working directory, but I cannot get it to work if I put it in a subdirectory and try to use the `basePath` feature of JsTestDriver.  Has anyone got this to work?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

### First the directory structure that works:

```
├── fixtures
│   └── fix.html
├── jsTestDriver.conf
├── lib
│   └── JsTestDriver-1.3.5.jar
├── server.sh
├── test
│   └── dom.fixture.test.js
└── test.sh
```

The jsTestDriver.conf looks like this:

```
server: http://localhost:9876

# files in the server section are only added if explicitly asked for        
serve:
  - fixtures/fix.html

test:
  - test/dom.fixture.test.js

timeout: 10
```

The server.sh and test.sh invoke the server and test-runner respectively:

server.sh:

```
PORT=9876
java -jar lib/JsTestDriver-1.3.5.jar --captureConsole --port $PORT --browser "/usr/bin/firefox;%s,/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome;%s;--allow-file-access-from-files"
```

test.sh

```
java -jar lib/JsTestDriver-1.3.5.jar --tests all --captureConsole
```

And I load the fixture in the dom.fixture.test.js code like so:

```
function getFixtureContent() {
  var url = '/test/fixtures/fix.html';

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, false); // synchronous!
  request.send(null);

  return request.responseText;
}
```

This successfully returns the html in fix.html, which I have to then load into the DOM.

But when I push the jsTestDriver.conf file into a conf directory, I can't seem to get the embedded jetty server in JsTestDriver to find the fix.html file without using absolute path (`/test//$HOME/javascript/jstd/fixtures/fix.html`), despite numerous variations attempted.  By default, JSTD assumes the `/test` root for Jetty to be relative to where you put the jsTestDriver.conf file. Supposedly, setting `basePath` should allow you to change that.

### Here's an attempt that fails:

Directory structure is the same, except jsTestDriver.conf is in a conf dir:

```
├── conf
│   └── jsTestDriver.conf
```

the paths in the jsTestDriver.conf have all been adjusted to be down a directory:

```
server: http://localhost:9876

# files in the server section are only added if explicitly asked for        
serve:
  - ../fixtures/fix.html

test:
  - ../test/dom.fixture.test.js

timeout: 10
```

and server.sh and test.sh have two additional command line switches:

```
--basePath .. --config conf/jsTestDriver.conf
```

The rest is the same.

The error is:

```
<h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /test/fixtures/fix.html. Reason:
<pre>NOT_FOUND</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>
```

I have tried it with versions 1.3.5 and 1.3.4.b.  Same result.  Thanks to anyone who can help solve this mystery.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying version 1.3.3d - we've had to stay on this version due to a [bug in relative path calculation](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/issues/detail?id=223) that was fixed for that version, but seems to have been reintroduced as a regression for 1.3.4, and is still a problem with 1.3.5.